# Convert folder to .bin-File

Tags: linux, software-installation, executable, conversion

I just downloaded a bin file for my new application.

The problem is that I had to change some config files, and for that I used 7-zip to unpack the files. I changed the files the way I want to have them, but now I don't have a way to convert the files to a bin file as downloaded before.

I renamed it to .bin, but the shell said that it can't execute a folder.
So, how can I handle this problem?

Comment: A "bin" file sounds like it could be just about anything. Can you [edit] your question to include what `file path-to-the-bin-file` says it is.

Comment: I meant to say the *downloaded* file.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this bin file is some sort of packed installer and while 7-zip could open it, there's almost a zero chance you can reverse the process.